# Ruby on rails: Undefined method 'let'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am a newbie in Ruby on Rails, when I try method let in static_pages_specs.rb

```
   require `spec_helper` 
   describe "Static pages" do

      let(:base_title) { "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" }

      describe "Home page" do
        it "should have the title 'Home'" do
          visit '/static_pages/home'
          expect(page).to have_title("#{base_title} | Home")
        end
      end

    end
```

I get an error

```
    Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
         ActionView::Template::Error:
           undefined method `let' for Class:0x000000034b2230>:0x0000000374a6c8>
```

My Gemfile look like this

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    ruby '1.9.3'

    gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

    group :development, :test do
        gem 'sqlite3'
        gem 'rspec-rails'
    end

    group :test do
        gem 'selenium-webdriver'
        gem 'capybara'
    end 

    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    gem 'turbolinks'
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

    group :doc do
    # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
       gem 'sdoc', require: false
    end

    group :production do
       gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
       gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
    end
```

Also my spec_helper.rb look like this

```
      ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
      require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
      require 'rspec/rails'
      require 'rspec/autorun'

      Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

    # If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
      ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

      RSpec.configure do |config|

    # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
      config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
      config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
      config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

      config.order = "random"
      config.include Capybara::DSL
    end
```

Do you have any ideas what am I missing? I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

Edit: Already tried let bang method but it still gets the same error.

In the previous post I forgot to put

```
    require 'spec_helper'
```

in, but my code actually DID have it.
Sorry about that but it was not actually the problem there.

Solved: Thank you guys I've just solved it, it was just a silly typing in one of my templates.

Comment: Try with let bang method like -> let!(:base_title) { "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" }

Comment: I've already tried it, still no luck, am I missing any library or gem that my ubuntu cannot recognize method let?

Comment: Post your static_pages_specs.rb file. may be you need to add rspec helper so it may happen that your specs can not recognize let and other stubs and mocks.

Comment: @Graeme McLean's answer gives you solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `static_pages_specs.rb` is missing `require 'spec_helper'`:

```
require `spec_helper`

describe "Static pages" do
  ...
end
```

Comment: You are right about that, I forgot to put it in the post but my file actually had that line. Sorry and thank you for pointing that. Do you have another idea?

Comment: How are you running rspec?  Also, please share your `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: I used the 'rspec_rails' gem as described in my Gemfile.

Comment: I meant what command are you using to run the test?  e.g. `bundle exec rspec spec/views/static_pages_specs.rb`

Comment: I used embedded Ruby test for Sublime Text

Comment: Please add your `spec_helper.rb` to the question.

Comment: Could you try running the test from the command line - `bundle exec rspec spec/requuests/static_pages_spec.rb`.  The error you are getting `undefined method 'let' for Class` suggests it thinks the spec file is just a Ruby class rather than `#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::...`